# I'm unable to pass route params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, ionic4

I'm passing a route param from the calling page with the following code:

```js
   showProfile(id: string) {
    const navigationParam: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        userId: id
      }
    };
    console.log('navParm', navigationParam);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('view-profile', navigationParam);
   }
```

console.log shows navigationParam with the data.  However, the console log on the view-profile page is not

```js
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('params', params);
    });
  }
```

[image: The console log on the view-profile page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `navigate` function for this, there an [issue when passing queryParams](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798#issuecomment-386065087) with `navigateByUrl`:

```
 this.router.navigate(['view-profile'], navigationParam);
```

In your view-profile page:

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
             private router: Router ) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params['userId']);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**parent.ts**
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor( public router: Router, )    

this.router.navigate(['/view-profile', { id: your params variable}]);

**view-profile.ts**

import { ActivatedRoute,  } from '@angular/router';
constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
 ) {

let data = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
console.log(" data ", data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**parent.ts**

```
 openDetailsWithState() {
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: {   \\create state like object
    user: this.user \\this.user is your  array this method using pass array ,u can avoid pass data inside URL bar
  }
};
this.router.navigate(['details'], navigationExtras);
```

}

**Child.ts**

```
data: any;


constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) { \\Get value from state
    this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
  }
});
```

}

This  is Best solution